# Create Django a foreign key field with a child value

Tags: python, django

To summarize my problem, I want to create a foreignKey field to show all of the songs a user has. For each song a user has I also want to see how many times that same user has played a specific song.

```py
class Songs:
   song = models.CharField(max_length = 30)


class Profile:
   user = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   songs_available = models.ForeignKey(Songs, models.SET_NULL blank=True, null=True,)
```

Thanks for the reply. I took your advice and I still don't get it. I made some changes.

```
class Plays(models.Model):
    plays = models.IntegerField(default = 0)


class Song:
   song = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   plays = models.ManyToManyField(Plays, through='Profile')


class Profile:
   user = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   songs = models.ForeignKey(Song, models.SET_NULL blank=True, null=True) 
 plays = models.ForeignKey(Plays, models.SET_NULL, blank=True,null=True)
```

In DJ admin profile, fields 'songs' and 'plays' show up but they look like regular M2M fields.

Comment: M2M field with `through` option and separate model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I took your advice and I still don't get it. I'm fairly new at this. I made some changes.

Comment: class Plays(models.Model):
 plays = models.IntegerField(default = 0)


class Song:
   song = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   plays = models.ManyToManyField(Plays, through='Profile')


class Profile:
   user = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
   songs = models.ForeignKey(Song, models.SET_NULL blank=True, null=True) 
 plays = models.ForeignKey(Plays, models.SET_NULL, blank=True,null=True)

In DJ admin profile, fields 'songs' and 'plays' show up but they look like regular M2M fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about many to many field with additional options(in your case, it would be amount of plays) in django.