# Django object that allows a user to see how many times they played a specific track

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield, generic-foreign-key

User purchases a unique song. Each time they play the song, their unique song count for that song increases. Does Django allow this?

I was told to read the django documentation on foreign keys and m2m using through. I'm not getting the results I want. Would kindly appreciate being pointed i the right direction.

```
class Plays(models.Model):

    plays = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    plays = models.ManyToManyField(Plays, through='profile',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class profile(models.Model):    

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,  null=True, blank=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE) ##

    songs = models.ForeignKey(Song, models.SET_NULL, blank=True,null=True)
    plays = models.ForeignKey(Plays, models.SET_NULL, blank=True,null=True)
```

I just want the user to see how many times they played a song and be able to change the song count each time by one increment. 
I want to be able to see u1 =  profile.objects.get(user = user)
print(u1."Song_One".plays) output 4.
(u1."Song_Two".plays) output 1.
Have another user u2 do the same thing
u2."Song_One".plays output = 10
and etc.
I hope I explained this correctly.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You should have a M2M relation between `Song` and `Profile` that uses `Plays` as the `through` table and have FK's to both `Profile` and `Song` in your `Play` model.

Comment: @Selcuk Okay, if I am understanding this correctly. I need to change
plays = models.ManyToManyField(Plays, through='profile',)
to plays = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, through='Song',).

Comment: That's right (and remove `songs` and `plays` from profile). Simply put the "many" table is the `through` one, so you should have more than one `Play` instance (for every user-song pair).

Comment: @Selcuk Yes! Thank you! I have it working now!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Django a foreign key field with a child value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56436871/create-django-a-foreign-key-field-with-a-child-value)